# What is limiting the speed of HTTP requests over localhost?

Tags: python, http, networking, tcp, fastapi

When I try sending a 10MB HTTP request from my server to my client both running on the same machine, it takes ~2s to complete. I would expect it to be faster since all the data is just moving over localhost loopback. I followed [this article](https://pencilflip.medium.com/what-is-iperf-5f1943d6781) to test my localhost speed and it showed ~2000MB/s, at that speed a 10MB request should take 5ms.

Why does my HTTP request take so long and how can I speed it up?

The context for why I'm asking is that I am trying to make a web based GUI for my Python project and it needs to display large data tables. I thought a web-based GUI could be just as fast as native frameworks like tkinter since over localhost the HTTP request time should be negligible. I tried FastAPI, Flask, Tornado and ExpressJS, but they all had similar slow performance.

`server.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
                   allow_methods=["*"],
                   allow_headers=["*"],
                   allow_origins=["*"])

DATA = 'x' * 10 ** 7


@app.get("/api/data", response_class=PlainTextResponse)
def _():
    return DATA


uvicorn.run(app, debug=False, port=8000)
```

`client.py`

```py
import requests
import time

start = time.time()

response = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/api/data")

end = time.time()
duration = (end - start)

print(duration)
print(f"Response size: {len(response.content) / 1048576} MB")
```

Comment: I am not sure why but to make requests faster you can use the concurrent module (specifically the ThreadPoolExecutor). URL: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#:~:text=The%20concurrent.futures%20module%20provides%20a%20high-level%20interface%20for,which%20is%20defined%20by%20the%20abstract%20Executor%20class.

Comment: @VRComp Would that really speed up single large requests though? It seems like that just allows parallel tasks which would increase the number of requests per second (which is also what most web framework benchmarks focus on) but my use-case is large non-concurrent requests between a server and a single client on the same machine, not serving many clients with parallel requests.

Comment: As I see it you have response.get() under a for-loop iterating 5 times. Therefore, you are making 5 requests in total even though those requests are the same.The ThreadPoolExecutor should help with that.

Comment: @VRComp Oh that was just to get an average time for request duration to demonstrate that the HTTP requests are taking 0.5 seconds, in my actual project I am interested in reducing the time of single large requests (and understanding why there's such a big discrepancy between localhost speed and actual HTTP request time)

Comment: @pyjamas: You are not solely measure the time of HTTP. You also measure the time it takes to serialize the data at the server into a JSON and to deserialize the data at the client from JSON. This might take longer than just transferring the data.

Comment: just giving my 2 cents here...have you tried benchmarking the function only? Or even only the instruction `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}] * 10 ** 6` in order to see how fast it is supposed to be and how much overhead the HTTP request + web server add

Comment: @Isabi @Steffen Ullrich I updated my example to instead return a simple 10MB string of 10mil `x` characters so there's no serialization. This takes 2 seconds to run. I'm confused though because when I use `axios` in my browser console it says 46ms, Postman takes 0.5s, and Python it takes 2 seconds...

Comment: @pyjamas Have you tried a different port instead of 8000? Also try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1. The network lookup is slow on localhost. With an explicit address it should be faster.

Comment: @VRComp Wow using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost the request only took 50ms. I thought they were equivalent why is localhost significantly slower? `socket.gethostbyname('localhost')` returns `127.0.0.1` in 1ms

Comment: You might have `localhost` mapped to both ipv6 and ipv4. uvicorn does not listen on ipv6 in your case. ipv6 then gets tried first, times out and then ipv4 is tried instead. That delay might be what you're seeing.